# Android 4.2 cache error

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-file

I have this error when i try to :

```
File file = new File(cacheDir, fileName);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

cache dir is from :

```
context.getCacheDir();
```

And the error is:

> 11-30 12:38:34.029: E/BitmapFactory(18814): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.android.test/cache/file_name: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

This is my void to write the file:

```
public static void writeFile(Bitmap bmp, File f) {
        if (bmp == null)
            return;

        FileOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(f);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, out);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null)
                    out.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
        Log.i("app", "path: "+f.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

In this void, the Log.i in the end print the same file path as the error one.

I have this error ONLY on device with android 4.2. till android 4.1.x all works fine.

Comment: no exception ? do you have space left on the device ?

Comment: i have bought my nexus 7 yesterday, so yes i have free space :) .. same error on my friend's galaxy nexus whit 4.2

Comment: can you post your full logcate error?

Comment: My app doesn't crash, i haven't an errore tree in the logcat only that exception and as result in the app bitmaps aren't displayed

Comment: I have done a lazy image loader so i have a task that download the file in the background and then send a message to a handler in the activity, then the activity try to read the file with the voids above. The really strange thing is that i have this error only after update to 4.2. On my smartphone with 4.1 all works fine. I have read something about multi user and directory emulation introduced in 4.2 maybe the problem could be there, but this should be completely transparent to developer. or maybe they have changed the behavior of the cache, i dont know :(